# ListView Searching

Tags: android, mysql, listview

This is my code with my custom adapter,I have listview populated with the mysql data but doing searching in edittext shows zero result.

```
        lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViews);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);


        items=new ArrayList<Client_information>();
        adapter=new Client_storeAdapter(getApplicationContext(),items);

        lst.setAdapter(adapter);

        Thread thread=new Thread(doInBackground);
        thread.start();

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("hello", "hello");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
        });

 }
 Runnable doInBackground=new Runnable()
 {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        items = Client_service.getAllRadioclient(myValue);
        runOnUiThread(runOnUi);
    }

 };

 Runnable runOnUi=new Runnable()
 {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        for(Client_information radioitems:items)
        {
    adapter.add(radioitems);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 };
```

}

This is my code with my custom adapter,I have listview populated with the mysql data but doing searching in edittext shows zero result.

Comment: Post your filter code which is inside of your adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
    }
     
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
    }
     
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```

in Manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

like this

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

Comment: yes for the mysql database. I tried your method but its not working bro.